# Maintaining session timeout globally in java spring configuration

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Below is my code to maintain a session timeout globally in Java spring configuration and to load the session timeout value from a properties file. Do you have any suggestions to improve my code?

```
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    @Override
        public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
            try {
                ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                InputStream stream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("bimspring.properties");
                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.load(stream);
                String sessionTimeout = properties.getProperty("cookieName", "No Value Found");
                event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(Integer.parseInt(sessionTimeout));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite a number of points for this short piece of code:

- As the properties file will probably not change at runtime, loading it every single time a session gets created is a total waste. See whether you can cache the session timeout in a static variable.
- If the value is not set, the default "no value found" will lead to a number format exception. Better use a sensible parseable default.
- Similar context: by setting the value to a non-parseable string, you can kill the server with a misconfiguration.
- "sessionTimeout" should not be named "cookieName"
- Separation of concerns: a method should do *one* thing. This is a mixup of reading the program configuration and using the determined value to set the timeout.
- Error handling: printStackTrace does not accomplish anything. Do something real (e.g. log an error for the server admin, shutdown, whatever.) If you decide to continue the process in case of an I/O exception, set a sensible default on the session.